# Update data in mongodb with input valors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have three input to obtain three different values. Im using express.js , node.js, mongodb and ejs templates.

```
<form action="/save-profile/<%= user.id %>/<%= user.name %>/<%= user.lastname %>/<%= user.description %>" method="POST">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Name</span><%= user.username %>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="'John'" aria-label="Username" name="username">
            <span class="input-group-text">lastName</span><%= user.lastname %>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Server" name="lastname">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-text">Description:</span>
            <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" placeholder="" name="description"><%= user.description %></textarea>
        </div>
        </p><br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mb-10 btn-lg">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In js file:

```
router.post('/save-profile', async (req, res) => {
const profile_id = await User.findById({ _id: req.body.id })
const updatedName = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.body.username})
const updatedlastname = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ apellido: req.body.lastname })
const updatedDescription = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ description: req.body.description })
console.log(profile_id,updatedName,updatedApellido,updatedDescription)
res.redirect('/profile')})
```

I tried to do it with a get but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly, `action` attribute in the `form` tag accepts the `path` where you are handling the form data. You only need to pass the `user.id`, there's no need to pass the other fields for this use-case.

```
<form action="/save-profile/<%= user.id %>" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

2. Secondly, in your route handler, the database record can be updated using only a single `findOneAndUpdate` call. You don't need to call it multiple times for every field if you're only going to update a single record.
3. The path written in `action` attribute will appear as `/save-profile/1`, for instance, in your route handler. Value preceding `/save-profile/` i.e. `1` can be accessed by modifying the path in route handler as `/save-profile/:id` and in the callback you can get it by `req.params.id`

Finally you have this.

```
router.post('/save-profile/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const response = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    {
      username: req.body.username,
      apellido: req.body.lastname,
      description: req.body.description
    },
    { new: true }
  )
  // Do something with response  
  res.redirect('/profile')
})
```